# Adding Timestamps To Packet Payload with TCPREPLAY

Tags: linux, networking, timestamp, pcap

I have a pcap file to replay. I want to rewrite packet payload to include a timestamp. How can I do that with [tcpreplay](http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/wiki/tcpreplay#tcpreplay) or [tcprewrite](http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/wiki/tcprewrite#tcprewrite)? Is there a default option or should I implement it myself (modifying tcpreplay)? I have been reading these pages for a while and google did not help me either. Thanks in advance

PS: I don't want to modify the original size of the packet, since the data is not important overwriting is fine. If only option is to modify packet size, I am fine with that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That kind of editing isn't supported by tcpreplay/tcprewrite, so you'd have to write the code yourself.  If you don't mind corrupting your packet data (which sounds like you're ok with) then it should be pretty easy by editing tcpedit.c.

Comment: thanks for the response. Will it hurt the forwarding performance a lot due to frequent system calls?

Comment: Well that depends... gettimeofday() used to be very expensive on most systems, but things have improved significantly the last few years.  Linux for example has switched from a BIOS call to the HPET which is a lot faster.   Assuming you're just putting a 4 byte UNIX epoch timestamp in the packet via memcpy() that would be pretty fast and low overhead.  If you want higher accuracy, that's more bytes and potentially more work/overhead, but it really depends on your implementation.    Long story short, you shouldn't notice a real performance hit under most conditions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not bound to a command line tool, checkout [netdude](http://netdude.sourceforge.net/). It is GTK application which allows you to edit a packet trace using just a few clicks.

Here is a screenshot that shows the dialog to edit the TCP header fields.

[image: TCP header editing]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://netdude.sourceforge.net/screenshots/0.4/shot-1.gif))</sub>

The accompanying library [libnetdude](http://netdude.sourceforge.net/doco/libnetdude/index.html) is the core of netdude. Write your own tool with it if the GUI provided by netdude does not meet your needs.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I need to replay around gpbs traffic. I will compare performance of libnetdude against tcpreplay.

Comment: In this case, [Click](http://www.read.cs.ucla.edu/click/click) might be a better choice for your problem scale.

Comment: Actually this would be a traffic generator to a click router. I choose to include timestamps in traffic generator rather than stamping them in click hoping to get a better pps on click machine but I am not sure what kind of performance I would get timestamping them in click.